# Raw microphone data from in-ear mic of bluetooth headphones?

Tags: audio, raw-data, headphones

I'm looking for a way to access the raw microphone data of in-ear microphones in bluetooth in-ear headsets (say the Pixel Buds series). Does anybody know if that is possible, or if there are any other devices where this where the raw data of all microphones is available?

I have tried to search for solutions using search engines, but sadly found no definitive answer. Google Fit API seems to allow for access of raw data (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors) but its unclear what sensor data is available.